# get distancematrix for two numpy arrays with different shapes

Tags: numpy, scipy, distance, reshape, broadcasting

I have the following arrays:

```
np.random.seed(3)
X = np.random.randn(10,20)
Y = np.random.randn(10,5)

D_x,N = np.shape(X)
D_y,M = np.shape(Y)
assert D_x == D_y
```

I want to calculate the distancematrix for L2 norm without using for loops by using the following formula:

```
A = sp.transpose(X)@X
B = sp.transpose(X)@Y
C = sp.transpose(Y)@Y

D = A - 2*B + C
```

The shapes of the arrays don't match as they have different N but the same features. I tried to work around with np.tile, reshape etc. but so far I didn't manage to broadcast them properly.
Thank you so much.

Comment: What distance matrix would you make with loops?  We shouldn't have to guess,

Comment: sorry, you are absolutely right.  I edited it.